# Getting data from mysql and creating a csv file issue

Tags: php, sql, csv

I want to extract some data and create a csv file. This is how my **attributes** table looks like. you can see it in the picture:
[HERE](http://attin.netlogiq.eu/stackoverflow/poza.png)

This is my code, what i tried:

```
$select = mysql_query("select * from attributes");
$final =""; 
$i = 0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($select)) {
    $id_produs = $row['id_produs'];
    $n_attr = $row['nume_attr'];
    $val = $row['val_attr'];
    $final .= $id_produs . "%%"  . $val . "%%";
    $csv_array_attributes[$i] = $final;
    $i++;
}
```

This is the part when i create the CSV file:

```
$file = fopen("attributes.csv", "w+");
foreach ($csv_array_attributes as $line) {
    fputcsv($file, explode('%%', $line), "^", "`");
}
fclose($file);
```

AND this would be the wanted result: [HERE](http://attin.netlogiq.eu/stackoverflow/poza2.png). So, the `nume_attr` should be the header for every column in the csv and the `val_attr` should be the values for every `nume_attr` (see the image).

I tried many ways but I don't get this result from the image. I have to mention that my table "attributes" has more than 74000 rows.

This is the table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `attributes` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `id_produs` text NOT NULL,
  `nume_attr` text NOT NULL,
  `val_attr` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=673912 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: should i provide any more information?

Comment: What is the result you are getting?

Comment: see the result here http://attin.netlogiq.eu/it4profit/attributes.php

Comment: @Malcolm Kindermans But now i need a query and the position of each attribute name somehow to put their the attributes values and i dont know how to get it

Comment: is there someone to help me with this ?

Comment: It is much easier for "ah, i got a minute" fiddlers like me to help you if you'll provide the table structure and example data not as a picture but valid `CREATE TABLE ....` and `INSERT INTO ....` statements.

Comment: @VolkerK I updated my post please check the table structure

Comment: you can DOWNLOAD ALSO the table from here: http://attin.netlogiq.eu/stackoverflow/test.zip

Comment: can anyone give me maybe an idea how to solve this ?

Comment: I guess no one can help me :(, thx for the help anyway

Answer (score 0):

```
/*Try following code */     
$select = mysql_query("select * from attributes"); 
        $i = 0;
        $csv_array_attributes[$i]=array('sku','manufacturer_article','manufacturer');
        $i++;
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($select)) {
            $csv_array_attributes[$i] =array('sku'=>$row['id_produs'],'manufacturer_article'=>$row['nume_attr'],'manufacturer'=>$row['val_attr']);
            $i++;
        }

        $file = fopen("attributes.csv", "w+");
        foreach ($csv_array_attributes as $line) {
            fputcsv($file,$line);
        }
        fclose($file);
```

Comment: Thx for the help, but i want to get columns from attribute name, see the image in my post. also you can get the db from my comments

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume speed isn't the issue here and neither is concurrency, i.e. you just want the result now no matter how good, bad or ugly the solution is ;-)

First query all the attribute names via `SELECT DISTINCT nume_attr FROM attributes`
Store those names as *keys* of an array with empty string values, i.e. you should have an array like

```
$template = array(
  'Manufacturer Article' => '',
  'Manufacturer' => '',
  ...
)
```

Make a variable that stores the currently processed id_produs (start with *false*).
Make a variable that stores the current "csv"-record ( again start with false )
Query all records ordered by id_produs and iteratore over the result.
If the current record has a different id_produs than the "currently processed" write out the current "csv"-array and start anew with the template array created in the first step and the current id_produs as ...the current id_produs. For each record write the val_attr value to the key nume_attr in the csv array.
You will have to check/write the last record after the iteration.

Comment: I dont want to be rude, but can you provide also the code, I just want to understand better what are you sugesting. thx in advance. and yes i dont care about speed and concurrency

Answer (score 0):

```
/* try following code,and reply if it will helpful to you or not */

$select = mysql_query("select * from attributes"); 
$i = 0;
$i++;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($select)) {

    $csv_array_attributes[$row['id_produs']][$row['nume_attr']] =$row['val_attr'];
    $i++;
}

$arraytempheader=array();
$arraytemp=array();
$arraytempheader[0]="";

$j=1;
foreach ($csv_array_attributes as $Colname=>$alline) {

    if($j!=1)
    {
        foreach($arraytempheader as $key=>$val)
        {
             if($key!=$j && $key!=0)
             $arraytemp[$Colname][$key]="";
        }   
    }

    foreach ($alline as $keyline=>$valline)
    {   
        $arraytempheader[$j]=$keyline;
        $arraytemp[$Colname][$j]=$valline;
        $j++;
    } 
}

$file = fopen("attributes.csv", "w+");
fputcsv($file,$arraytempheader);   

foreach ($arraytemp as $Colname=>$alline) {
    $finalArray=array();
    $finalArray[]=$Colname;
    $finalArray=array_merge($finalArray,$alline);
    fputcsv($file,$finalArray);          
}
fclose($file);
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to fix this in other way.

Here you select the attributes and store them into array

```
$select = mysql_query("select * from attributes");
$rezultat=array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($select)) {
    $id_produs = $row['id_produs'];
    $n_attr = $row['nume_attr'];
    $val = $row['val_attr'];
    //$final .= $id_produs . "%%"  . $val . "%%";
    $rezultat[] = array('id'=>$id_produs,'attr'=>$val);
}
```

And here you write them to the file.

```
$file = fopen("attributes.csv", "w+");
foreach ($rezultat as $line) {
    fputcsv($file, $line, "^", "`");
}
fclose($file);
```

Comment: This won't combine multiple attributes per product into a single line.

Comment: I got this of the result of your code: Warning: explode() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given in /home/netlogiq/public_html/MAGENTO/CUSTOM/attin/it4profit/attributes.php on line 84

Warning: fputcsv() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given in /home/netlogiq/public_html/MAGENTO/CUSTOM/attin/it4profit/attributes.php on line 84

Comment: please check my comments i post a link with the table structure and content , thx for the help

Comment: I'm not sure how you want to be the needed csv result. Give an example